# Weird looking binned residual plot

Tags: residuals, generalized-estimating-equations

[image: Binned Residual Plot]

My binned residual plot is quite strange looking, the 95% confidence lines are so very jagged, with points between.  I have colored this "inside" of the 95% confidence interval because it is really hard otherwise to tell which points are inside and which are outside.  This plot was made in R.  This is from a generalized estimating equation-logistic regression, with many correlated clusters and a AR-1 correlation structure.  I am not sure if this is a reasonable way for this plot to look or if I have done something wrong.  Has anyone else had a plot that looks like this?  Thanks in advance,
Jesse

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly obvious that the distribution of outcomes are integer valued and you have some sort of positive relationship between the outcome and the predictor of interest. That creates the stratified "downward sloping" lines in the residuals. Luckily, residual plots are practically irrelevant. It comes as no surprise given that these residuals are produced from a logistic regression which models the risk of a binary outcome. Residuals from a logistic regression make 0 sense except for calculation of a Brier score for risk prediction. More specifically, your x-axis is "expected values" that are on the *log-odds* scale $\mbox{logit}(\pi)$. whereas the outcome is on the risk scale, $\pi$. So in particular, these residuals should have a slight S curve shape to them, but the variability in the distribution of your exposures is not great enough to drive that association. Hence, they appear approximately linear.